# PostGIS Query Geometry Field Truncated

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql

Some of the geometry fields that are returned from my PostGIS queries are truncated. When I first found this error any geometry fields with more than a few thousand characters would not show up in the pgAdmin Output Pane. So I changed the `pgAdmin >> Options >> Query Editor >> Max Characters per column` to 32,500 and now the geometry field shows up but it is truncated and ends with "(...)" like the following example;

```
MULTIPOLYGON(((
    -79.4660582160837 42.211909028322,
    <<..coordinates>>..
    -79.4673861587629 42.212436007559,
    -79.4673871980406 42.212436150477 
   (...)
```

Any query that ends with the "(...)" fails when I attempt to serialize the result. This occurs on any geometries that have more than a couple thousand characters in them.

I'm pretty sure the issue has something to do with these large geometries because I can successfully run geometries that have fewer vertexes.

When I first found this bug I thought it might be restricted to PostgreSQL 9.2 so I installed version 9.3 and have found the same issue. I also reindexed my table and as far as I can tell the table is not corrupt.

I am also using PostGIS 2.2 bundle for PostgreSQL x64 9.3.

Comment: How are you performing the serialisation?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the data? Why is this a problem? Are you trying to copy / paste from the output pane?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the issue. It appears that in .NET there is a limit to how long a string that is serialized can be and you must explicitly declare a maxJsonLength in your Web.config. I was able to solve the problem by adding the following to my Web.config:

```
 <system.web.extensions>
        <scripting>
            <webServices>
                <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
            </webServices>
        </scripting>
    </system.web.extensions>
```

This did not change how the result appeared in the pgAdmin output pane but now I can serialize my PostgreSql result set and pass it back to my web application.

Comment: Might be worth editing your question to make clear that the truncation was happening from a .NET call and was nothing to do with postgres...